# lvs output : Data% column

Tags: lvm, lvs

Following is a example of standard lvs output:

```
LV    VG     Attr       LSize   Pool  Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
POOL  VG     twi-aotz-- 399.80g              28.12  14.75
```

The

```
Data%
```

field specifies the percentage of data the pool or volume is filled as a percentage of it's total size.

Could you please let me know which column name it's corresponds to.

I checked man lvs and looked at the columns:

```
Column  names include: chunk_size, convert_lv, copy_percent, data_lv, devices, discards, lv_attr, lv_host, lv_kernel_major, lv_kernel_minor, lv_kernel_read_ahead, lv_major, lv_minor, lv_name,
          lv_path, lv_profile, lv_read_ahead, lv_size, lv_tags, lv_time, lv_uuid, metadata_lv, mirror_log,  modules,  move_pv,  origin,  origin_size,  pool_lv,  raid_max_recovery_rate,  raid_min_recov‐
          ery_rate,  raid_mismatch_count,  raid_sync_action,  raid_write_behind,  region_size, segtype, seg_count, seg_pe_ranges, seg_size, seg_size_pe, seg_start, seg_start_pe, seg_tags, snap_percent,
          stripes, stripe_size, sync_percent, thin_count, transaction_id, zero.
```

Could not find anything which maps to Data%.

It would be also good to have the value as exact value and not percentage.

The way to dump specific columns in lvs is:

```
lvs -othin_id,lv_name,origin,lv_size
```

I am looking for what should I append at the end of the columns which are being dumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
lvs -o data_percent
lvs -o help (more info).
```

sorry I'm not speak english well...
I'm not rude. :)

Comment: I confirm this works for me.